# How to post Google Spreadsheet row data to a specific url?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to post Google Spreadsheet data to a specific URL just as we post form data, but I want to do this inside the Google script editor, I have tried this way:

```
function postdata() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test Sheet");
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var newData = new Array();
    for(i in data){
        var row = data[i];  
    }
}
```

I am able to get each row data but I don't know how to post this row data to a URL.

Comment: What do you mean by "post this row data to a URL"? Are you referring to [fetching](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach yes exactly

Comment: you'll most likely need to map it into an object that you pass along with it, what and how depends entirely on the API you're querying and what your data looks like.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach okay thanks, i have posted an answer by using your reference

Answer (score 1):

With the [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) given by [Robin Gertenbach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5426909/robin-gertenbach) i am finally able to create the script:

```
    for(i in data){
        var row = data[i];

        if((row[12] > 10) && (row[12] < 20)){

            var aUrl = "https://secure.pluginext.com/familyoptin/record?fname="+row[1]+"&lname="+row[2]+"&email="+row[0]+"&tel="+row[7]+"&address="+row[3]+"&city="+row[4]+"&state="+row[5];

            var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(aUrl);

        }
    }
```

i hope this would help someone. :)